# How to make a single Storm cluster to read from multiple Kafka sources?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

There are multiple Java web service clusters. They all produce log streams to local Kafka. Clusters do not overlap in that way, i.e. they only produce data to Kafka that belongs to the same cluster. New topics may be created by services.

Is it possible to setup my Storm cluster to read and aggregate the data from all of my data sources considering the dynamic nature of global topic set? Storm topologies are not flexible to add a remove specifics on the fly. So am I doomed?

Comment: do you plan to have kafka topics being created "on the fly"?

Comment: Yes, they are created on the fly. Or rather I can't predict what topics introduced/updated services may generated.